# Does the data size of an SSD chip have compatibility issues with certain boards?

Tags: storage, ssd, intel

I'm considering getting an 8TB SSD storage chip for my Intel NUC mini-server (I install linux on it). However, I'm wondering if there are any considerations one needs to take when adding that much storage space.

Will the NUC have a hard time doing read/writes with that much storage? Let's say I had a 100 TB SSD chip, would that affect performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the NUC have a hard time doing read/writes with that much
> storage?

No, there are limits to disk size for all interfaces but the SATA and NVMe options you have in your NUC won't be remotely troubled by an 8TB disk - that's not that big in pro sysadmin terms.

> Let's say I had a 100 TB SSD chip, would that affect performance?

Often the bigger the SSD the higher the performance, to a limit anyway, also the amount of wear levelling increases too.

You may also find that follow up questions regarding non-server hardware like NUCs might be better asked on our sister sites superuser.com - which is designed to handle consumer computing questions.